# How to use Gurobi quicksum in Python to write this expression?

Tags: python, gurobi

I am trying to figure out how to write this constraint for Gurobi in Python.

[image]

```
for j in city:
   for i in frequency:
     c2 = m.addConstr(gp.quicksum(x[i,j]) <= 1, "c2")
```

But I am getting this error and I am a bit confused why it is wrong...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you that the `quicksum` function's argument is expected to be an iterable and a single Var object isn't iterable. Instead, you could do something like this:

```py
c2 = {}
for j in city:
    c2[j] = m.addConstr(gp.quicksum(x[i,j] for i in frequency) <= 1, "c2")
```

Alternatively, you could use the [`.sum()`](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_tupledict_sum.html) method:

```py
c2 = {}
for j in city:
    c2[j] = m.addConstr(x.sum('*', j) <= 1, "c2")
```

PS: You probably want to store the constraints in a dictionary if you want to access them later. At the moment, you're only storing the last constraint in the variable `c2` as it gets overwritten with each loop iteration.

Comment: Hey Joni! Thanks for the help! Just a follow-question, so are you saying that "x[i,j]" is a single Var object but "(x[i,j] for i in frequency)" is a iterable?  I am confused because I thought both my loop expression's logic are the same, like I thought "gp.quicksum(x[i,j] for i in frequency" is just writing a loop in one line.

Comment: Yes and yes. I think you are confusing the addConstr() method with addConstrs(). The latter allows you to write `m.addConstrs((gp.quicksum(x[i,j] for i in frequency) <= 1) for j in city)` instead of the loop in my answer.